# Why does creating a new Objective-C class file in XCode4 not create a "An Objective-C class, with a header that includes the <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> header."

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, templates, xcode4

When I create a new Objective-C class file in XCode 4 it creates two files:

one whose content is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private

}

@end
```

and one whose content is:

```
#import "MyClass.h"


@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I'm a beginner working out of a Dummies book, and This is not what I'm used to seeing in XCode3 when I create a new file. Plus, the wizard says the file should have a `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` in the header, but these files have `Foundation.h` in the header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading an old book.  If you take a look Cocoa.h it is importing:

- #import *Foundation/Foundation.h*
- #import *AppKit/AppKit.h*
- #import *CoreData/CoreData.h*

This was the standard practice for most Cocoa application on Mac OS X.  Now, that we have iOS it doesn't use AppKit.framework; iOS uses UIKit.framework. So the template is only going to import *Foundation.h* only. This way you can use your subclass in a project that targets the Mac OS X or iOS platform.  This way you don't have to write #define statements for the different platform.

If you take a look at the pre-compiled header (.pch) for a Mac OS X project it will import Cocoa.h for you which import *AppKit.h*.  And the iOS project .pch imports *UIKit.h*.

Answer (score 1):

By

- Looking at Xcode Templates `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates`
- Especially at Cocoa templates in `Cocoa/` folder

I can see that :

- `NSDocument`, `NSView`, `NSViewController`, `NSWindowController` templates are importing `Cocoa.h`
- `NSObject` aka the magical `___VARIABLE_cocoaSubclass___` in template is the only one importing `Foundation.h`

That's what you can see in interface :[image: Xcode create class]

So explanation is simple, *despite description of "Cocoa" templates*, if you're using a Cocoa class as listed above, `Cocoa.h` will be imported, otherwise, `Foundation.h` will be.

That makes sense since templating is not smart enough to determine what should be imported, and that a good coding practice is to import the minimum possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your project you have a **MyProjectName-Prefix.pch** file. This is your Pre-Compiled-Header file. 
Headers listed in here are automatically included in every other header in your project in a more efficient way (the 'pre-compiled' bit). 
If you open it you will see `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`